# Tornar as checkbox selecionadas, conforme dados do banco!

Tags: cakephp

Conforme o código abaixo, preciso fazer com que ao carregar a página, uma tabela seja carregada com os checkbox marcados, conforme dados do banco, por exemplo:

```
                Destino
             _______________________________________
    Origem  |   1   |   2   |   3   |   4   |   5   |
    --------|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|
       1    |       |   X   |       |       |       |
    --------|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|
       2    |       |       |   X   |       |       |
    --------|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|
       3    |       |       |       |   X   |       |
    --------|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|
       4    |       |       |       |       |   X   |
    --------|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|
       5    |       |       |       |       |       |
```

Onde o `X` seria conforme o banco de dados, formando o seguinte `array`:

> ```
>    $transicao => array(
>               (int) 0 => array(
>                       'origem' => 1,
>                       'destino' => 2
>               )
>               (int) 1 => array(
>                       'origem' => 2,
>                       'destino' => 3
>               )
>               (int) 2 => array(
>                       'origem' => 3,
>                       'destino' => 4
>               )
>               (int) 3 => array(
>                       'origem' => 4,
>                       'destino' => 5
>               )
> ```

### Código atual:

*Copiando e colando o código [neste site](http://phptester.net/), você verá o mesmo em funcionamento*

```
<?php

   $status = array(
              [
                  'origem' => 1,
              ],
              [
                  'origem' => 2,
              ],
              [
                  'origem' => 3,
              ],
              [
                  'origem' => 4,
              ]  
   );

//simulando dados do banco de dados
   $transicao = array(
              [
                  'origem' => 1,
                  'destino' => 2
              ],
              [
                  'origem' => 2,
                  'destino' => 3
              ],
              [
                  'origem' => 3,
                  'destino' => 4
              ],
              [
                  'origem' => 4,
                  'destino' => 5
              ]  
   );

echo "
<table cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>
    <tr> <!-- Aqui é montado a primeira linha da tabela que é a do cabeçalho -->
        <th> ORIGEM </th>";
        foreach ($status as $xkey => $xvalue) : 
            echo "<th bgcolor='#cccc0'> " . $xvalue['origem'] . "</th>";
        endforeach;
        echo "</tr><tr>";
    //      foreach que percorre as colunas
            foreach ($status as $ykey => $yvalue) : 
                echo "<td bgcolor='#ddddd'> " . $yvalue['origem'] . "</td>";
                foreach ($status as $xkey => $xvalue) :
                    $value = $yvalue['origem'] . '|' . $xvalue['origem'];
                    echo "<td>
<input type='checkbox' name='origem" . $value . "destino value='" . $value . "'>
                    </td>";
                endforeach;
                echo "</tr>";
            endforeach; 
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Quando for dar o "echo" no input, faça uma verificação pra ver se aquele deve ser marcado, se for o caso coloque o atributo checked="checked".

Comment: Pois é José, eu fiz isso, porém ainda não encontrei a lógica correta pra marcar somente aqueles que existe no banco de dados, quando faço essa verificação, ele marca alguns e aí fica sobrando outros checkbox caso tenha algum marcado, estou tentando aqui, qualquer coisa eu posto o resultado, se você tiver outra alternativa ficarei grato pela ajuda xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solução encontrada:

Criei uma variável `$marcado` dentro do `foreach` que percorre o `array $x` para fazer a inserção dos `checkbox`, inicializei a variável como `false` (assim: `$marcado = false;`) e depois fiz a seguinte verificação:

Se `$yvalue` (origem) for igual à `$transicoes_value['origem']` (origem do array `$transicoes`) e `$xvalue` for igual à `$transicoes_value['destino']` (destino do array `$transicoes`), então eu seto a variável `$marcado = true`.

> ```
> if ($yvalue == $transicoes_value['origem']
>  && $xvalue == $transicoes_value['destino']) {
>     $marcado = true;
> }
> ```

Após eu imprimo o `checkbox` caso a variável `$marcado` seja igual a `true` eu imprimo o `checkbox` com a propriedade `checked="checked"` se não, imprimo normal sem a propriedade `checked="checked"`.

### Assim:

```
if ($marcado == false) {
    echo "<td>
        <input type='checkbox' 
               name='origem" . $value . "destino value='" . $value . " 
               checked='checked'>
    </td>";
} else {
     echo "<td>
        <input type='checkbox' 
               name='origem" . $value . "destino value='" . $value . ">
    </td>";
}
```

### Código final:

*Copiando e colando o código [neste site](http://phptester.net/), você verá o mesmo em funcionamento*

```
<?php

   $status = array(
              [
                  'origem' => 1,
              ],
              [
                  'origem' => 2,
              ],
              [
                  'origem' => 3,
              ],
              [
                  'origem' => 4,
              ],
              [
                  'origem' => 5,
              ] 
   );

//simulando dados do banco de dados
   $transicao = array(
              [
                  'origem' => 1,
                  'destino' => 2
              ],
              [
                  'origem' => 2,
                  'destino' => 3
              ],
              [
                  'origem' => 3,
                  'destino' => 4
              ],
              [
                  'origem' => 4,
                  'destino' => 5
              ]  
   );

echo "
<table cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>
    <tr> <!-- Aqui é montado a primeira linha da tabela que é a do cabeçalho -->
        <th> ORIGEM </th>";
        foreach ($status as $xkey => $xvalue) : 
            echo "<th bgcolor='#cccc0'> " . $xvalue['origem'] . "</th>";
        endforeach;
        echo "</tr><tr>";
    //      foreach que percorre as colunas
            foreach ($status as $ykey => $yvalue) : 
                echo "<td bgcolor='#ddddd'> " . $yvalue['origem'] . "</td>";
                foreach ($status as $xkey => $xvalue) :
                    $marcado = false;
                    $value = $yvalue['origem'] . '|' . $xvalue['origem'];
                    foreach($transicao as $transicao_key => $transicao_value) :
                    if ($yvalue['origem'] == $transicao_value['origem']
                     && $xvalue['origem'] == $transicao_value['destino']) {
                        $marcado = true;
                    }
                endforeach;
                if ($marcado == true) {
                    echo "<td>
      <input type='checkbox' 
             name='origem" . $value . "destino value='" . $value . "
             checked='checked'>
                    </td>";
                } else {
                    echo "<td>
      <input type='checkbox' 
             name='origem" . $value . "destino value='" . $value . " '>
                    </td>";
                }
                endforeach;
                echo "</tr>";
            endforeach; 
echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode verificar se existe o array do checkbox dentro dos dados que estão vindo do banco com o `in_array`

```
$checked = (in_array(['origem'=>$yvalue, 'destino'=>$xvalue], $transicao) ? 'checked="checked"' : '');

echo "<td>";
    echo "<input type='checkbox' name='origem" . $value . "destino value='" . $value . "' ".$checked.">";
echo "</td>";
```

Comment: Cara, pra mim não funcionou, devido aos arrays bidimensionais.
o `in_array` não funciona em arrays bidimensionais (se não me engano)

Comment: o `in_array` verifica se um objetivo igual contém dentro do array, somente se o seu array estiver diferente do origem/destino que você citou no exemplo, fiz o teste com o seu código e funcionou certinho.

Comment: Tens razão, eu coloquei o array `X` e `Y` dessa forma para melhor ser entendido o que eu estava falando, porém o `array X` e `Y`, seria um `Array status`, vou editar para melhor ser entendido.